# How to show a bottom navigation drawer when clicking navigation icon on BottomAppBar?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation, material-components-android

So, I made a memo Android app, and I've used the new material **BottomAppBar** with a FAB, and I want to show a bottom navigation drawer when I press on the hamburger item (R.id.home) on my BottomAppBar, but I all what I've found on the Internet was regular Navigation drawers (that expand from the side).

Also, the BottomAppBar allows me to choose only a still icon for the navigation icon using `app:navigationIcon` attribute, while I want to have the same animated hamburger icon that converts to an arrow.

Here's my main `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/noteList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/note_view" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
        app:fabAnimationMode="slide"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="40dp"
        app:hideOnScroll="true"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_24dp" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_create_24dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bar"
        app:rippleColor="@color/rippleColor" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Note: I'm trying to make an app like Reply (a Material design study) that's available on [material.io](https://material.io/design/material-studies/reply.html).

Comment: There’s an article from a publication named “Material Design in Action” on Medium which addresses your needs here: https://medium.com/material-design-in-action/implementing-bottomappbar-menu-and-navigation-c4f069e579ec

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Edric. That was very helpful!